# Karate API Tests - API POST request unable to send body when Content-Type is application/jwt

Tags: karate

For POST api having body as jwt karate is unable to send body having content-type as application/jwt.

Whereas while i perform the same through Postman it works. Let me know if i am missing anything.

My API request is:

```
1 > POST "Sever URL"
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 4959
1 > Content-Type: application/jwt
1 > Host: auth-sandbox.apiboitest.com
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_144)
```

here the body is not getting passed which is been sent:
    Given url DCRurl
    And header Content-Type = 'application/jwt'
    And request payload_body_of_type_jwt
    When method POST

Comment: the example that you have shared do not have content-type as application/jwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- see if you are missing an `Accept` header that postman may be sending
- try to convert the value of the `request` to string before making the request
- try `* configure charset = null` before making the request if the server does not handle the charset, which is passed as `UTF-8` by default

Otherwise there is not enough info to tell what is wrong from your question.

Comment: Please see postman request. Same is not getting replicated in Karate.           POST /1/api/open-banking/v1.2/register/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api-sandbox.apiboitest.com
Content-Type: application/jwt
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bbfac0bf-da6c-4def-b972-70a3bf6a6c4a
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImU1MlRMcVVuMXhxbnZrTUtZblhPZGRtODYtTSJ9.eyJncmFudF90eXBlcyI6WyJhdXRob3JpemF0aW9uX2NvZGUi

Comment: @ruchiramore this doesn't help at all, sorry. try get the help of someone who knows the api. or try to get a cURL request working - then it would be easy to derive the karate steps

Comment: Thanks Peter, i will not be able to send you the entire cURL .     curl -X POST \
  https://api-sandbox.apiboitest.com/1/api/open-banking/v1.2/register/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/jwt' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: d8764654-626c-4071-9a92-0e30a99ef770' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImU1MlRMcVVuMXhxbnZrTUtZblhPZGRtODYtTSJ9.eyJncmFudF90eXBlcyI6WyJhdXRob3JpemF0aW9uX2NvZGUiLCJyZWZyZXNoX3Rva2VuIiwiY2xpZW50X2NyZWRlbnRpYWxzIl0sIm

Comment: Also let me know if Content type 'application/jwt' works in karate?

Comment: @ruchiramore yes

Comment: can you please give me an example for the same. I will try to replicate it

Comment: @ruchiramore JWT example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/jwt/jwt.feature

Comment: none of the examples have application/jwt as content type

Comment: karate supports anything in HTTP and any content-type as long as you build the request body correctly. I pointed you to a JWT example. there is no example for that specific content-type. so it is up to you now.

Comment: Thanks Peter, sadly it doesnt help me. JWT wasnt the issue . Anyways thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi Peter i have marked this as accept , yet i am unable to pass content-type as application/jwt

Comment: When content type gets passed as application/jwt body is not gettiing passed at all

Comment: @ruchiramore you can keep commenting or wasting your time or you can follow this process, so it is up to you now: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue